# Database Attache Upgrade Fail?

Tags: upgrade, database, content-database

I ran the mount-spcontentdatabase and it failed.  The test-SPContent Database didn't produce anything in the log that would fail the upgrade.  Also, the error report didn't have anything that would have failed either?  I read that it might be a disk space limit, however, it was turned off.  Now when I try to run the Mount-SPConentDatabase it says that I have to run the AssignNewDatabaseID cmd, which is not working.  Any advice would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: What was the error message when you attempted to run Mount-SPContentDatabase?

Comment: You can try attaching with the addcontentdb stsadm operation, sometimes this works when Mount-SPContentDatabase does not? See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287634.aspx for use.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the upgrade status in Central Admin since it provides much more insight into the upgrade process including how long it’s been running, number of errors & warnings, and even what step it’s on in the process? I think url is http://CA/_admin/upgradestatus.aspx . Also try to paste additional ULS logs if possible.

`Mount-SPContentDatabase` is best when it comes to attaching multiple parallel databases to the farm.  Essentially is nearly the same as the `STSADM –o addcontentdatabase`.  It does actually have more options when you start looking at parameters on the surface in each command.  This is where the power of powershell competes on a command level.  If you’re doing parallel content database attach for example, this powershell method is recommended.  You’d simply run each of these in different command/management windows.

Did you also try to run `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase` as it is strictly for resuming the failed upgrade. It can be used on in-place upgrade failures for failed databases or database attach upgrade failures.  In contrast the `STSADM –o Upgrade` command can resume binary and database upgrade, but more holistically.  I’ve found the STSADM to be the fail safe command as it will check both the binaries and all of the databases.  If you have problems with one particular database the `upgrade-spcontentdatabase` will obviously the best choice to target the resume of the upgrade.  It’s not just used for failures, but to restart the upgrade of a database where issues have been addressed.

Here is the quick summary of upgrade:

1. Verify the hardware requirements first.
2. Try to back up the database from SharePoint 2007 using the SQL Server Management studio.
3. Move the backup file to SharePoint 2010 environment and restore the backup file in SQL Server in a New Database (say DB1_2010)
4. Before you attach the DB to web app, run the following powershell: Test-SPContentDatabase –Name DB1_2010 -WebApplication http://test:14212
5. You will get to know the errors, fix the errors first and then try to attach the DB using following stsadm command: STSADM –o addcontentdb –url http:// test:14212/ -databasename -databaseserver

Problem will likely due to some customizations. But step 4 will help you eliminate the errors before you run a successful upgrade.
Here is the very [nice and easy tutorial](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/upgrading-content-database-sharepoint-2010-database-attach-method/) on how to migrate/upgrade from 2007 to 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the database id was already available in Config database.

Where this database come from?

If you are adding the database from same server means, first removing the database from Web application properly, and then add the database to web application. Otherwise we may face the error like "AssignNewDatabaseid"